# Magento links in admin wont work

Tags: magento

After login in the back end the admin menu won't work.

Only the first button/menu "Dashboard" and "logout" will be working.

All other menu-items don't link.

Anyone has got an idea how I can solve this problem?

Comment: Did you merge your Magento js files?

Comment: sorry what you mean in detail?

Comment: now also the function "add to cart" in frontend wont work - in the console i find "ReferenceError: Ajax is not defined" - what going on here?

Comment: In magento we have an option to merge js files. Are you getting any errors in browser console?Try to view page source and copy js files path and open in new tab.see if it oepns?

Comment: there are a lot of js files, for wich one i have to look?

For example http://www.domain.com/skin/frontend/base/default/js/msrp.js

This file can open.

Comment: If your site is online(public) can you share frontend url?

Comment: In you site no js file is accessible. Try to open mentioned file in new tab of browser. (Have you done some recent changes?)   http://www.presentim.com/js/prototype/prototype.js

Comment: Do you have js folder in your Magento root check once.

Comment: no in the root folder is no subfolder "js"

Comment: i dont under stand why but the folder was in a backup and i dont know why it was delete now - i copy the folder up to the server and it works - i thank you a lot ;-)